# Is there an addon to update (refresh/reload) a page with enter on URL even with hash?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

When the URL contains `#something` and we press enter on the URL bar nothing happens. Is there an addon that forces the page to update (refresh/reload)?

Example:

```
http://anypage.com/#anything (press enter)
```

Page doesn't reload.

I want the same behavior as Google Chrome, if you press <kbd>enter</kbd> it reloads the page.

Comment: Which URL is this ? IT's quite possible that the site itself does not know how to handle the fragment.

Comment: @Sathya: Any. Firefox doesn't refresh the page (load as if it were the first time). Google Chrome reloads (load as if it were the first time) any page with hash.

Comment: I had to open Firefox to understand what you're asking in the question. Unfortunately, I cannot find any addons which do want you want to happen. Perhaps a (very bad) alternative is to refresh every x minutes- on second thought I really doubt that will work.

Answer (score 3):

This [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=186371) was reported eight years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of one. I suppose you know about keyboard shortcuts like F5 and Control+R?

Comment: Both resend post request, which I want to avoid. To workaround I have to delete the hash and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I figured out a way that works.

Create a bookmark in the bookmarks toolbar, with the following url:

`(function(){url=window.location.href.split('#');url=url[0].replace(/\?\d+?$/,'')+'?'+(new Date()).getTime()+'#'+url[1];window.location=url})()`

When you click it, it adds an extra parameter to the end of the url (before the `#`), which is updated every time you click it.

- `http://test.com/foo#bar`
- `http://test.com/foo?123#bar`
- `http://test.com/foo?124#bar`
- etc

Most servers will ignore a double querystring, so it shouldn't interfere with other `?foo=bar` parameters. Enjoy!